# Node unable to load native module 'profiler.node'

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying use the library [another-v8-profiler](https://github.com/pflannery/another-v8-profiler) , but when I try execute the server, the message is displayed:
unable to load native module 'profiler.node' from ./build/Release/profiler or ./compiled/win32/x64/v
0.10.12/profiler

Some has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did `npm install another-v8-profiler`, did you see any errors or any compilation output? You could try `npm install node-gyp -g` and then changing to the module's root directory and do `node-gyp rebuild`. If successful, go back to your project's directory and try starting the server again.

Comment: I tried running the npm install node-gyp -g as administrator and works, but when I executed the node-gyp rebuild
$ sudo node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.13.0
gyp info using node@0.10.26 | linux | x64

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.26',
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"

Comment: Don't use sudo. Just do `node-gyp rebuild` in another-v8-profiler's root directory.

Comment: Without sudo 
gyp ERR! clean error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink 'build/config.gypi'
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rrampone/pdc/project/pdc_poc
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: Sounds like the use of sudo when installing the module may have messed up permissions. Try blowing away that node_modules (if nothing else in it, otherwise just remove the another-v8-profiler subdirectory) and just do `npm install another-v8-profiler`. Paste the output you get from that into a pastebin or gist.